# Проблема с прогнозированием на Keras

Tags: python, keras, tensorflow

Товарищи, подскажите в чем проблема. Строю простенькую нейросетку в Гугл Колабе. Использую Керас. Выглядит она так:

```py
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(units=16, input_dim=10, activation="relu"))
model.add(Dense(units=32, activation="relu"))
model.add(Dense(11, activation="softmax"))
model.compile(loss="categorical_crossentropy", optimizer="adam", metrics=["accuracy"])

history = model.fit(X_train, Y_train, batch_size=200, epochs=100, validation_split=0.2, verbose=2)
```

Что касается данных, они не связаны друг с другом, как при временных рядах, поэтому активация выходного слоя: softmax. Количество нейронов входного и скрытого слоя, а также функцию потерь подбирал через перебор гиперпарамметров. На вход подаю нормализованные данные (10 переменных). Вот пример:

```py
array([[0.11764706, 0.41666667, 0.06666667, 0.46666667, 0.3125    ,0.46153846, 0.25      , 0.21428571, 0.17746479, 0.45810811],
       [0.        , 0.41666667, 0.        , 0.2       , 0.1875    ,0.23076923, 0.25      , 0.57142857, 0.32535211, 0.26486486]
        ... и так далее ])
```

На выходном слое 11 нейронов, которые на тренировочной выборке получают нечто такое:

```py
array([[0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]
       ... и так далее], dtype=float32)
```

В тестовой выборке подобные данные. Тренирую на 3000 наблюдений, а тестирую на 300.
Сразу скажу, что пример использовал с задач по предсказанию датасета MNIST, но адаптировал под свою. Само собой я не ждал от этой сетки какой-то высокой точности на начальном этапе, но то что я получил, честно скажу, не ожидал:
[image: сравнение актуальных данных и предсказанных]

Предсказания варьируются от 2 до 3 (за редким исключением до 4), когда исходные данные от 0 до 10. Не могу понять где я накосячил и в чем может быть проблема. Датасет MNIST предсказывается подобной архитектурой на ура. Пускай для моих данных точность была бы низкой, но хотя бы предсказания охватывали весь диапазон возможных состояний (как я и писал от 0 до 10). Подскажите в чем может быть проблема или на что обратить внимание. Может кто с подобным сталкивался. Заранее спасибо.

UPD: увеличил количество эпох до 1000 и поменял функцию потерь на 'mse'. Теперь прогнозы варьируются от 1 до 5. Не знаю что такое можно сделать, чтобы, пусть и с ошибками, но от 0 до 10 выдавала.

Answer (score 0):

Киньте ссылку на Коллаб данный. Куском оценить тяжело. 
А так...очень много косяков.У вас и предсказывания неверны и обучение тоже.
Softmax дает вероятность класса. К нему должен быть подключен fullyconnected слой. Плюс mnist на 10 цифр(0-9), а у почему-то 11 значений.

```
model = models.Sequential()
model.add(layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=(32, 32, 3)))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Flatten())
model.add(layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax'))

model.compile(optimizer='adam',
          loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
          metrics=['accuracy'])

history = model.fit(X_train, Y_train, batch_size=200, epochs=100, validation_split=0.2, verbose=2)
```

Рекомендую попробовать разбивать сразу, при загрузке на выборки обучающие и тестовые и тд,удобнее сравнивать.(к примеру x_train, y_train, x_test, y_test). Но это дело вкуса. Так же сменить на бинарную кросс энтропию функцию.
Если ваша цель ознакомиться с ИНС и научится слои писать - смотрите гит и документацию. Если обучить, чтобы использовать - лучше используйте [стандартные оптимизированные сети](https://keras.io/applications/) с обучением или без.

```
from keras.applications.resnet50 import ResNet50
model = ResNet50(weights='imagenet')
```

Рекомендую строить под данной схеме в связке [tensorflow и keras](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/images/cnn).Так же [пример на гитхабе](https://github.com/aymericdamien/TensorFlow-Examples/blob/master/examples/3_NeuralNetworks/convolutional_network.py).